# 3month rolling correlation keeping date column in R

Tags: r, correlation, finance, rolling-computation

This is my data. Daily return data for different sectors.
I would like to compute the 3 month rolling correlation between sectors but keep the date field and have it line up.

```
> head(data)
        Date Communication Services Consumer Discretionary Consumer Staples  Energy Financials - AREITs Financials - ex AREITs Health Care
1 2003-01-02                -0.0004                 0.0016           0.0033  0.0007              0.0073                 0.0006      0.0370
2 2003-01-03                -0.0126                -0.0008           0.0057 -0.0019              0.0016                 0.0062      0.0166
3 2003-01-06                 0.0076                 0.0058          -0.0051  0.0044              0.0063                 0.0037     -0.0082
4 2003-01-07                -0.0152                 0.0052          -0.0024 -0.0042             -0.0037                -0.0014      0.0027
5 2003-01-08                 0.0107                 0.0017           0.0047 -0.0057              0.0013                -0.0008     -0.0003
6 2003-01-09                -0.0157                 0.0019          -0.0020  0.0009             -0.0016                -0.0012      0.0055
`
```

My data type is this

```
$ Date                          : Date[1:5241], format: "2003-01-02" "2003-01-03" "2003-01-06" "2003-01-07" ...
     $ Communication Services        : num [1:5241] -0.0004 -0.0126 0.0076 -0.0152 0.0107 -0.0157 0.0057 -0.0131 0.0044 0.0103 ...
     $ Consumer Discretionary        : num [1:5241] 0.0016 -0.0008 0.0058 0.0052 0.0017 0.0019 -0.0022 0.0057 -0.0028 0.0039 ...
     $ Consumer Staples              : num [1:5241] 0.0033 0.0057 -0.0051 -0.0024 0.0047 -0.002 0.0043 -0.0005 0.0163 0.004 ...
     $ Energy                        : num [1:5241] 0.0007 -0.0019 0.0044 -0.0042 -0.0057 0.0009 0.0058 0.0167 -0.0026 -0.0043 ...
     $ Financials - AREITs           : num [1:5241] 0.0073 0.0016 0.0063 -0.0037 0.0013 -0.0016 0 0.0025 -0.0051 0.0026 ...`
```

Currently what I am doing is this:

```
rollingcor <- rollapply(data, width=60, function(x) cor(x[,2],x[,3]),by=60, by.column=FALSE)
```

This works fine and works out the rolling 60 day correlation and shifts the window by 60 days. However it doesnt keep the date column and I find it hard to match the dates.

The end goal here is to produce a df in which the the date is every 3 months and the other columns are the correlations between all the sectors in my data.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the information at the top of the [r](/questions/tagged/r) tag and, in particular provide the input in an easily reproducible manner using `dput`.  In the absence of that we will use `data` shown below based on the 6x2 BOD data frame that comes with R and use a width of 4.  The names on the correlation columns are the row:column numbers in the correlation matrix. For example, compare the 4th row of the output below with `cor(data[1:4, -1])` .

`fill=NA` causes it to output the same number of rows as the input by filling with NA's.

```
library(zoo)
# test data
data <- cbind(Date = as.Date("2023-02-01") + 0:5, BOD, X = 1:6)

# given data frame x return lower triangular part of cor matrix
# Last 2 lines add row:column names.
Cor <- function(x) {
  k <- cor(x)
  lo <- lower.tri(k)
  k.lo <- k[lo]
  m <- which(lo, arr.ind = TRUE)  # rows & cols of lower tri
  setNames(k.lo, paste(m[, 1], m[, 2], sep = ":"))
}

cbind(data, rollapplyr(data[-1], 4, Cor, by.column = FALSE, fill = NA))
```

giving:

```
        Date Time demand X       2:1       3:1       3:2
1 2023-02-01    1    8.3 1        NA        NA        NA
2 2023-02-02    2   10.3 2        NA        NA        NA
3 2023-02-03    3   19.0 3        NA        NA        NA
4 2023-02-04    4   16.0 4 0.8280576 1.0000000 0.8280576
5 2023-02-05    5   15.6 5 0.4604354 1.0000000 0.4604354
6 2023-02-06    7   19.8 6 0.2959666 0.9827076 0.1223522
```